# Number of ways to choose up to K values from a set of size N

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Is there some existing rule for this? Let's say I have a group of 14 and I want to see how many ways I can pick up to 8 people from this group.

I know it would simply be ${14 \choose 1}$ +  ${14 \choose 2}$ + ${14 \choose 3}$ + ... ${14 \choose 8}$ but is there a simpler expression of this?

Comment: It appears that there are bounds, as seen in this MathOverflow post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Comment: using $\sum_{i=0}^{14} \binom{14}{i} = 2^{14}$, we get your sum as $2^{13} -1  + \binom{14}{8}$, so for large $n$, this sum should be $ \approx 2^{n-1}$